# PC goes into endless reboot. No POST/beeps. PC has internal RAID so I'm afraid to swap out mobo & screw up the drive array (I didn't configure it)

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, raid, reboot

I have a PC workstation which has been working just fine for the last several years. As of a few days ago, when I power it on it goes into an endless reboot loop. It switches on for 1-2 seconds, then powers down. Then powers back on, and so on indefinitely. It does not post, there are no beeps, or any video signal.

Normally I would just try and replace each component until I isolate the problem, but with this machine there's one issue: the motherboard has an internal RAID controller that's been set up with four hard drives to form a single volume. I didn't configure this RAID, and unfortunately the person who did passed away some time ago. I have no documentation on how it was done. I don't even know for sure what kind of RAID it was - I think it was a RAID 0 but I'm not sure. I know nothing about configuring RAIDs, So, I'm afraid if I replace the motherboard, or even try to reset the bios, my array config could be lost, and my data with it (I do have backups, but of course, they are not up to date...)

So I'm looking for some help in trying to pinpoint the problem, and ideally, maybe even some expertise on how to avoid wiping my data, if indeed I do need to swap or reset the motherboard.

Onto the machine. It's an older system, 2011-2012.

- Motherboard: ASROCK X79 Extreme 11 THX
- GPU: ASUS GeForce RTX 2070 Super Overclocked 8G EVO GDDR6 (recent upgrade)
- CPU: I don't know and can't see it
- RAM: 6 sticks of Corsair XR3 DDR3 16GB
- Power Supply: CORSAIR AX1200

What I've done so far:

- My first thought was the power supply. I replaced it with identical model. Didn't help.
- I then tried to unseat and reseat all the RAM. Didn't help.
- Then I tried taking out all the RAM except one stick in slot #1. Tried 3 different sticks. Same issue.
- I tried removing the GPU, to see if I could at least get some beeps - also no difference.
- I removed all PCI cards (it has a couple of other cards). No difference.

Here is what happens in the machine for the brief second it turns on:

- The case fans start
- the CPU heatsink/fan has a light-up Corsair logo that briefly lights up, flickering weakly
- The red LCD on the motherboard lights up for a fraction of a second (it doesn't have time to display numbers, just looks like an initialization)
- FWIW I noticed there is a fan on the board labelled "XFan" that doesn't spin.
- Then, after all that (which again, all happens in under a second), the board clicks and powers down. The case fans stop, everything turns off. Then it tries again to power on.

So there you have it. I am not sure what else I can do without risking my onboard RAID config being lost. I guess my next step would be to try and replace the CPU, but before I go and buy another CPU, I'm hoping there are some power users here who might have some ideas as to what could be wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: this sounds like "double-post." This happens in some cases when the memory or cpu timings are changed and the motherboard {does magic} and then recycles to regular boot.  If the settings cannot be written, then you might get stuck in the loop as the BIOS is trying to reset and re-detect. Given the age of the motherboard, the CMOS battery may be dead.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't wanted to replace the CMOS battery for fear it would wipe the RAID settings, do you happen to know if it would on this motherboard?

Comment: I don't; it seems to depend on implementation.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will keep digging!